using esvect math commands in section headings
The \vv{} syntax from esvect doesn't work in section headings. Other commands such as \mathbb{}, \textit{} and plain in-line math mode still do work. Only the esvect syntax doesn't seem to.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{esvect}
\begin{document}
\section{$\textit{Hello World!}$} % works
\section{$Hello\ World!$} % works
\section{$\vv{Hello\ World}$} % does not work
\end{document}


We see
% esvect.sty, line 43:
\def\vv{\@ifstar{\vvstar}{\ESV@vecteur}}

This defines a fragile command. For a single case you can get away with \protect\vv. Or you can make the command robust.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{esvect}

\MakeRobust{\vv}

\begin{document}

\section{The vector $\vv{x}$}

\end{document}


You can even do better and forget about \vv*.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{esvect}

\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\vv}{sme{_}}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\vvstar{#2}}% for old documents using \vv*
    {\ESV@vecteur{#2}\IfValueT{#3}{_{\mkern-1mu\relax#3}}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{The vector $\vv{x}$}

$\vv{x}+\vv{E}_{1}$

\noindent
$\vv{x}+\vv*{E}{1}$ % old syntax

\end{document}

I left the possibility of using \vv*, which might come handy in case you want to reuse code. But the new definition can distinguish if a subscript follows and add the kerning automatically. As you see in the example, the output is the same, but the syntax without * is much better.


This works - thank you. I am curious if there are any downsides to making the \vv command robust, considering that the syntax for doing so is one line. I would have thought the developers would implement such a code in the .sty? I'll use \protect for now, just in case; but I am curious.

@Jasper No downside I can think of. I add a different solution that avoids the need of \vv*.

It seems the issue is due to the \vv{} command from the esvect package not being compatible with section headings. You could use \boldmath or \bm as such:
\section{$\bm{\vv{Hello\ World}}$}

You can use it such as:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand{\vvv}[1]{\bm{\vv{#1}}} % Custom command for bold math vectors

\begin{document}

\section{$\textit{Hello World!}$} % works
\section{$Hello\ World!$} % works
\section{$\vvv{Hello\ World}$} % now works

\end{document}

